# Integrate AAD for React(Client-App) & .Net Core(API's) in Azure AppService

Tags: reactjs, .net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-appservice, microsoft-identity-web

I have developed a client app in ReactJs which is hosted in 1AppService & i have .netcore webapi hosted in another app service

Can we integrate Azure Active Directory from Authentication blade of AppService, without making any changes in codelevel of both react & .net proj.
or should download MSAL Packages in React and implement it.

**Note-** I have already implemented B2C with same architecture(React & .Net) with MSAL Packages and its working. can we achive same using Authentication blade in Appservice without code change
[image]

Comment: Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

Azure App Service provides built-in authentication and authorization capabilities (sometimes referred to as "Easy Auth"),
so you can sign in users and access data by writing minimal or no code in your frontend (react) and backend (.net).
Refer to this this doc [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization] that describes how App Service helps simplify authentication and authorization. In your case you would not have to write any code if you use use the Azure App Service.